# Javascript structure to provide varying levels of debugging code with ease

Tags: javascript, console.log

My [research] program is growing quite large, like many projects.  I also battle the fight between getting work done and teaching.  I would like to have different amounts of `console.log()` statements with just changing something like a global variable or similar.   This is similar to typing `--v` (or similar for VERBOSE) in some terminal/console commands to get extra help of what is going on during a process.  This way for normal working, I can have the level be `Normal`, but when I let a student come onto a project, I can have them set the level to `Verbose` so they can see what is going on to help catch up, as not all the students are familiar with JS and its humors :)

JS already has `console.log()`,`console.warn()`, and `console.error()` for different message intensities in code, but I am looking for something that  would be similar to `normal.console.log()`, `30ThousandFootHighLevel.console.log()`, and `giveMeEverythingYouGot.console.log()` so I can include the appropriate levels throughout the application.  I would then, in some global scope like place, would say something like `consoleLogLevel = 3; // 0-N with N being the most verbose`.

BONUS points if I don't have to write each log level , but rather when `giveMeEverythingYouGot.console.log()` shows all [lower/inclusive/previous] levels.

Any node packages? hard code examples?
Here is a basic [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/YvR8nyuOJBfWSQaxAF0a?p=preview) set up to help with suggestions.  THANKS!

```
var consoleLogArray = ['NORMAL','MIDDLE','VERBOSE'];
var consoleLogLevel = 3;

$(document).ready( function(){
  // Got to let me know we are starting in some cases
  console.log('VERBOSE MERSSAGE: Started');
  // Some Basic code
  var x = 5;
  var y = 10;
  var check = 2;
  if (!x+y === 14){
    // This should be a verbose log
    // This should only show in Verbose setting
    console.error('We have a variable assignment problem')
  }
  if(x/y === check){
    // This should be a middle level
    // This should only show in Verbose setting or Middle Setting
    console.log('Yup, 10 divided by 5 is still 2...') 
  }      
  // This should be a normal level
  // This should show in Normal, Middle, and Verbose settings
  console.log('Finished with no errors!'); 
})
```

Comment: This should be quite easy to do if you just have a function that conditionally decides whether to call `console.log` depending on the log level of the call and the current threshold level. Do you have a conceptual difficulty with this approach, or have you encountered a specific problem when implementing it?

Comment: I am having trouble implementing it myself.   In the case that it doesn't call the normal `console.log` as you say, what would it call?

Comment: It either calls `console.log` or it does nothing, depending on the log level of each particular message. If the message should not be logged, do nothing and ignore it. Messages with low priority simply aren't logged. Is that different from what you want? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you assign `verbose`, `middle`, and `normal` to those log messages. But I'm going to assume you know when you write the log statement which level you want it to be.

So, how about this?

```
log = {
    order: {
        "verbose": 0,
        "debug": 1,
        "warn": 2
    },

    log_level: "warn",

    verbose: function (arguments) {
        if (this.order[this.log_level] <= this.order["verbose"]) {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    },

    debug: function (arguments) {
        if (this.order[this.log_level] <= this.order["debug"]) {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    },

    warn: function (arguments) {
        if (this.order[this.log_level] <= this.order["warn"]) {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    }
}

log.verbose("This is verbose"); // doesn't print
log.debug("This is debug");     // doesn't print
log.warn("This is warn");       // prints

log.log_level = "verbose";      // change what level of messages we want

log.verbose("This is verbose"); // prints
log.debug("This is debug");     // prints
log.warn("This is warn");       // prints
```

This way log statements are semantic. To send a verbose log you call a function by that name: `log.verbose`. You can add arbitrarily many levels by extending the `order` object.

The functions for each logging function (`verbose`, `debug`, `warn`) are almost identical. I'm sure you can write some higher-level function that generates those functions. Let's leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)